# Why Do Airlines Still Use Tractor-feed Printers?

Tags: airline-operations, airport, airlines

Why do airlines still use those old dot-matrix tractor-feed printers at their gate counters? I’ve always thought that was hilarious.

Comment: This question is more related to the passenger side of aviation, which is better suited for [travel.stackexchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: My bad! Could a moderator move this to the travel SE?

Answer (score 4):

Probably note directly related to aviation, maybe more to airports than airlines:
Well, dot-matrix printers are expensive, but durable and print at very low cost and finally carbon copies (two, three or even four) of forms could be created. And replacing them will require a lot of software adaptions. 
I‘ve seen airports using text-user-interfaces (TUI via terminals), which are often working a lot of better (fast and efficient to use) then usual GUI applications. New stuff, is not automatically good.

Comment: IOW, if it ain't broke, why spend money to fix it?

Comment: Dot matrix printers aren't limited to a particular paper size, they can generate a continuous print out that doesn't need paginating